# Site not appearing with prefix www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns

I installed a wordpress site. The visitors can only see the site without the prefix WWW. If someone types the website name with www, there is a "site not installed page". I am with OVH hosting and they are blaming the wordpress but I am sure that someone without good knowledge answered as the problem was the same even before the wp installation took place. If I change wp url location in the backend to www.mysite.com there is a backend lockout till I edit the database directly with the url without www.

My questions:

1> How to make my website accessible with both versions of the url (www+no www)? I want the www to appear in the address bar.

2> I do not want SEO rank loss due to duplicate content.

Please help as the customer care sucks and for 2 weeks they cant solve this problem. I am sure someone out here can please provide a few steps which I can follow and implement what I want. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check with your hosting provider.  I think technically, they are different URLs.  Your host should be able to link both I would imagine.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for late reply. I fixed issue as my host configs the site according to primary domain selected in the multi-domain hosting. Host sucked big time and hence changing for full control. Cheers :)